# Deletion of a record from a file

Tags: c, file, delete-record

In below code I want to delete records by `fwrite(&emptyEntry...)` row. Below code works but when I try to make the entry obsolete by assigning all the struct members 0 or null like:

```
client.accountNo=0;
client.firstName="";
client.lastName="";
client.balance=0;
```

compiler gives me error by saying "expression must be lvalue". acccountNo and balance does not give any errors but firstName and lastName variable assignments underlined by the compiler. Do you know why causes this? Can I use the above code can not be used for deletion of records individually assigning struct members?

```
fread(&client, sizeof(struct carData), 1, filePointer);

if (client.accountNo == 0)
{
    printf("This record does not exist!!!!\n\n");

}

else
{

    fseek(filePointer, (del - 1)*sizeof(struct clientData), SEEK_SET);
    fwrite(&emptyEntry, sizeof(struct clientData), 1, filePointer);
    printf("Entry deleted.");
}
```

Comment: What is `struct carData`? Show more code.

Comment: You can't assign to strings with `=`, you have to use `strcpy()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
client.firstName[0] = '\0' ;
client.lastName[0] = '\0' ;
```

will solve your problem. That's because, the `string is an array of chars in C`, which is as long as it doesn't encounters a `\0` character. Now, if you will make the first `char = '\0'`, then the string would end there itself.

Comment: actually, string is an array of chars in every language (generalizing, I dont know every language lol)

Answer (score 2):

Replace

```
client.firstName="";
```

by

```
client.firstName[0] = 0 ;
```

which is roughly the same as

```
strcpy(client.firstName[0], "") ;
```

Remember that, unlike in other languages, there is no such thing as a `string` type in C.

Answer (score 1):

Probably fistName & lastName have declared as array and hence compiler is giving the error.

Comment: @Abhineet, I have used the word in my solution because in problem it was not mentioned about the structure declaration.

Comment: Exactly like that. I declared it as char carBrand[15]